# SQL query for two tables, ignoring resultsets from second table

Tags: sql

I wish to cast a query in two tables, but the result set should show only all results from the first table with the info from the second table linked with the first one, but there are many linked info, i just want the last linked information. eg

table 1

```
id_t1 | number | type
1        555     file
2        666     img
```

table 2

```
id_t2 | id_table1_fk | date_in | description
1        1             04/07       aaaaaaa
2        1             05/07       bbbbbbb
```

query

```
id_t1 | number | type | date_in | description
1        555     file     05/07     bbbbbbb
2        666     img       null      null
```

Comment: Left/Right Outer Join

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Jonathan Leite.  Perhaps it is only formatting, but I cannot understand the sample data that you have provided.  If you format into columns (as code) , with some sample data and your desired results, the answer to your question may become more clear.  You may also want to provide what you have tried so far, and what is wrong with the result.

Comment: I recommend that when you ask these kinds of questions, you provide the DDL and DML required to set up the test. With such information you get more accurate answers and get them more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    new_t2.date_in,
    new_t2.description

FROM 
    t1,
    (  SELECT * 
       FROM t2 
       WHERE id_table1_fk = t1.id_t1 
       ORDER BY id_t2 DESC 
       LIMIT 1
    ) AS new_t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.*, table2.date_in, table2.description
from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.id_t1 = table2.id_table1_fk
```

Comment: This wouldn't always work as expected. Since you are joining tables that have a one to many relationship, you have to aggregate results from table2. Otherwise, the SQL engine will truncate the results, but it may not truncate them in the way we expect. It is also leaving the behavior of the query up to the SQL engine...